# Create File using SharePoint REST API call But It couldn't edit or view

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, file, api

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Document')/Files/add(url='abc.docx',overwrite=true),
method: POST,
body: "This is my doc",
Headers: 
  Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
  X-RequestDigest: form digest value
  content-length:length of post body
```

According to the above configuration, I created the docx file in SharePoint site using rest API endpoint but it couldn't view or edit. It gives corruption error. Please give the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you already see the file uploaded to the real Sharepoint site?

(this is not an answer, for now I can't post a comment)